# sendmail not working in Slurm Workload Manager (works from command line)

Tags: email, server, sendmail, slurm

I have a problem sending email from Slurm Workload Manager. I am a normal user with limited privileges. When I ssh into my remote server, I am able to send email from the command line

```
sendmail user@gmail.com < mail.txt
```

and I receive the email to my gmail account. So far so good. However when I put the command in a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
sendmail user@gmail.com < mail.txt
```

and `sbatch` the script I do not receive an email and get the following warnings.

```
sendmail: warning: inet_protocols: disabling IPv6 name/address support: Address family not supported by protocol
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: disabling IPv6 name/address support: Address family not supported by protocol
postdrop: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
```

Ultimately I want to send a custom email to myself after a script that has been run by `sbatch` finishes, which will include logs from the output and error files. I am looking for any solution which helps me do this. Maybe there is some way to run a script after sbatch that is at the same level as when I simply type in the terminal. Or maybe there are some different mail configurations on the node that is running my script, and there is some way to change them, or my call of `sendmail` that takes into account the different settings.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Does it work from `srun`?

Comment: No. I get exactly the same error codes as shown above.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I can help. You can try asking your postmaster for help.

Comment: Ok sure. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Id just skip using sendmail, and use mail.

`#!/bin/bash
cat mail.txt | /usr/bin/mail -s "This is a subject" user@gmail.com`

Comment: I can use command `mail` from the terminal, but this command is not recognised when using `sbatch`. I get the error: `/var/spool/slurmd/job16995804/slurm_script: line 8: mail: command not found` :(

Comment: Thank you for the continued support. I put the following in a batch script (that also includes the other basics needed to run): `/usr/bin/mail -s 'hello' sturges.tom@gmail.com <<< 'hello'`. I get the error `/var/spool/slurmd/job17006688/slurm_script: line 8: /usr/bin/mail: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you remotely connect to the server and type ```which mail```

Comment: If I `ssh` into the server and type `which mail` from the home directory I get the message `/usr/bin/mail`. But I think the problem is that (now I'm not sure how to phrase this correctly), the problem is that the access and directory and priviledges and features etc. of the "terminal" from the "home" directory are different to that of the "sbatch".

Comment: If I put `which mail` into a batch script and submit it using `sbatch` I get the error: `which: no mail in (/net/slurm/releases/production/bin:/net/slurm/releases/production/sbin:/net/slurm/releases/production/bin:/net/slurm/releases/production/sbin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/plgrid/bazaarsat/utils:/opt/cyfronet/bin:/opt/cyfronet/pudo:/net/people/plgsturges/.local/bin:/net/people/plgsturges/bin:/opt/plgrid/bazaarsat/utils:/opt/cyfronet/bin:/opt/cyfronet/pudo)`

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are going to the same server ?

Comment: 100% sure yes I am

Answer (score 0):

You did not clarify whether you batch job runs in the same host where you launch it with `sbatch`, or maybe you are not aware of it. The slurm workload manager is usually used in order to distribute many user jobs on different equivalent computing nodes of a cluster, and it may be the case that the node(s) where your job actually runs do not have access to the external network or are configured differently from the front-end node you initially connect to.

You can check where you job is running with the `squeue` command and, if it is a different host and the syasdmin allows it, you can further `ssh` there to test.

Moreover slurm has its own internal facilities for sending mail to the user in particular cases (search for `--mail` in `man sbatch`) without need to modify the script; if the mailing system is well configured by the administrator, these facilities should work regardless of the node where your job is running.